# using and sequence in a loop to calculate values

Tags: python, loops

I am needing help with a code that I wrote to calculate density using the stoichiometry. With each execution it will create a unique text file and write the stoichiometry corresponding to the density in each unique text file. So once it executes the first time the 'stoich' will change to 2 then 4 and so on. Each text file it writes will have different 'stoich' values with the calculated density.

```
  den_U = 19.1 #density of uranium 238 g/cc
  den_C = 2.26 #density of carbon 12 g/cc

  molm_U = 238.02 #molar mass of Uranium g/mol
  molm_C = 12.0107 #molar mass of Carbon g/mol

  stoich = [1,2,4,10,100,200,500,1000,2500,3000,4000]


  for i in stoich:
      input = 'density_stoichiometry_'+str(d)+'_'
      file = open(input + '.txt', 'w')

      T_C = molm_C*stoich # calculates total mass of carbon 
      T_com = T_C + molm_U # calculates total mass of chemical compound
      per_C = T_C/T_com # calculates percent of carbon in compound
      per_U = molm_U/T_com #calculates the percent of uranium in compound
      den_com = den_U*per_U + den_C*per_C # calculates the total density 
      d = stoich

      file.write('density='+str(den_com)+ '\n')  
      file.write('stoichiometry=' +str(d)+ '\n')
      file.close()

      stoich = 1
```

The code gives me the error at 'T_C = molm_C*stoich' , saying I can not multiply a sequence by non-int of type 'float'. I'm assuming i'll have the same problem at 'd = stoich'. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is `T_C = molm_C*stoich` supposed to do? Perhaps you mean `T_C = molm_C*i`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have commented my code more. let me do that real fast

Comment: If `stoich` is the thing that you are looping over, don't use `stoich` as if it were a variable in the body of the loop.

Comment: Okay I just added comments, and i'll try what you said. thank you

Comment: The meaning of `stoich` is `[1,2,4,10,100,200,500,1000,2500,3000,4000]`. You are looping over that list. What do you expect `molm_C*[1,2,4,10,100,200,500,1000,2500,3000,4000]` to mean? Also, at the bottom of the loop you write `stoich = 1` which at that point destroys your list. What is `stoich = 1` supposed to do?

Comment: I believe this was a mistake in my code. Should there be anything at the end of the code the code so it goes to the next value in the list ?

Comment: I believe my code works now after deleting the Stoich = 1 at the end and changing what you mentioned in the first comment. thank you for your help!

Comment: You were almost there, I summarized the changes in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
den_U = 19.1 #density of uranium 238 g/cc
den_C = 2.26 #density of carbon 12 g/cc

molm_U = 238.02 #molar mass of Uranium g/mol
molm_C = 12.0107 #molar mass of Carbon g/mol

stoich = [1,2,4,10,100,200,500,1000,2500,3000,4000]


for i in stoich:
  fname = 'density_stoichiometry_'+str(i)+'_.txt'
  file = open(fname, 'w')

  T_C = molm_C*i # calculates total mass of carbon 
  T_com = T_C + molm_U # calculates total mass of chemical compound
  per_C = T_C/T_com # calculates percent of carbon in compound
  per_U = molm_U/T_com #calculates the percent of uranium in compound
  den_com = den_U*per_U + den_C*per_C # calculates the total density 

  file.write('density='+str(den_com)+ '\n')  
  file.write('stoichiometry=' +str(i)+ '\n')
  file.close()
```

I used `i` rather than `stoich` in the body of the loop, got rid of the pointless `d`, and replaced `input` (the name of a built-in function) with `fname`. I also combined the definition of `fname` to one line, since it detracts from readability to split its definition into two lines (with part of its definition embedded in a function call).